# How to use google performance tool in windows

Tags: c++, windows, linker-errors, google-perftools

I tried to use google perftools on Windows. I compiled the source code in VS2010 and started a new test project and tried to link the `libtcmalloc_minimal-debug.dll`, and it failed with following error:

> fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x338

What did I miss? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I searched around the Project page and found [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/source/browse/trunk/README.windows?r=82)

The important points are:

- solution file can be loaded into VS2003 or VS2005
- To use tcmalloc_minimal in your own projects, you should only need to
  build the dll and install it someplace, so you can link it into
  further binaries.  To use the dll, you need to add the following to
  the linker line of your executable:
  "libtcmalloc_minimal.lib" /INCLUDE:"__tcmalloc"

This file is a little older (Jan 2010), but may at least start you in the right direction

Comment: thanks for your kind help. I've read the docs and my dev enviroment is VS 2010, the tutorial didn't work. :(